# AngujarJs - ng-repeat + instance.$remove does not update view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two functions: One for deleting data and another one for updating data. The data comes from a Resource.query().

I'm using `ng-repeat` to go over every element in the collection. Since every element is a Resource object, I guess that I should be able to apply $save, $remove, ... operations.

The Html could be as simple as:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in data_collection">
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="togglePublish(data,'country')">RELEASE</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <button class='btn btn-danger' ng-click="remove(data)">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

why if I do:

```
// Arg: data is a Resource object from the collection
$scope.remove = function(data){
    data.$remove();       //  <-----   THIS DOES NOT MODIFY THE VIEW
}
```

But this is correctly updating the data:

```
// Arg: original_data is a Resource object from collection 
$scope.togglePublish = function(original_data, country){

    // Deep copy
    var copy = angular.copy(original_data);

    // Modifications over the copy
    copy = toogleRegionPublication(copy, country);

    Resource().update(copy).$promise.then(function(){
        // If update was taken, then update view value
        original_data.regions = copy.regions;    // <---  THIS MODIFIES THE VIEW
    });
}
```

Why one of them is having some effect on the view but not the one that involves the $remove operation? Why?

Comment: As far as I understand $remove is just a HTTP DELETE method call over to your restful resource.

Comment: okay... I though that it should delete too the data vble... so then the view would be updated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand

> $remove

is just a HTTP DELETE method call over to your restful resource.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `data` object from the view I think you can just remove it from the `data_collection` array. [See how to remove object from array.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357)

However, if you still need to call `http DELETE` to remove that `data` object from your database or something, you will need to do that as well.